# How can I create, monitor and run/stop a process in linux

Tags: php

I have a cron which runs every minute but the thing is it queues every request from the past minute and executes some tasks one after another. I want to run a background process which will run infinite time. I'll check if there is any new request came in & will process that immediately.

```
do {
    //do my stuff
} while(true)
```

I need to know the command to check if the process is running or not, if not then start this, else do nothing

FYI - I'm not a linux guy and dont know anything about bash or shell. I need PHP code which I can add in the every minute cron which will just monitor this process is running or not.

Comment: How did you create the cron, using a Webhosting PANEL or directly in a linux terminal?

Comment: from cpanel. the cron is running fine. the problem is it runs every 1 min, where in this 1 minute there could be 60 items to process which now got queued. Where if I could start processing immediately in every sec, all these 60 process could get finished in this 1 min

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a service control and/or a watchdog. You can use D. J. Bernstein [Daemontools](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CFMQFjAE&url=http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html&ei=HqCWUrS0DZCxsASexYD4Cw&usg=AFQjCNHzV9LWr3cXR8-_SSd8TwiuY99lzg&sig2=vJQqad9QjPgLn74K4vl2bQ) or similar software.

Also, if you want to do it in PHP you could, inside the start part of your daemon (that is what you are building) raise a flag (a file), then withing a cron job, run another program to check if the flag is raised (the file exist) every N minutes.

Comment: I'll try the PHP solution today and will let you know if thatwroked or not. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: In the PHP solution if for some reason the process got stuck, don't get why - the whole thing is inside try catch but no exception was thrown. so it sees the flag is set as 1 in DB where in reality the process isn't running